# Does SQLITE support Unique Key Statements

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to read in an SQL File in SQlite.

The File contains some Statements regarding keys, e.g. UNIQUE KEY Statements
Example below:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Persons (PersonID int,name varchar(255), LastName varchar(255), FirstName varchar(255), Address varchar(255), City varchar(255),UNIQUE KEY `ID1234567` (`name`));")
```

My question is, does SQLIte support statements of that kind? or do i need to filter them out?

When trying to execute the statement, I always get an

> OperationalError: near "KEY": syntax error

Comment: That's what is supported: https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html

Comment: So since the arrow from unique goes straight to the bracket, ist not supported?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `UNIQUE KEY` in the first place? The relational concept is `PRIMARY KEY`, not `UNIQUE KEY`. Keys are unique by definition. All databases have `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, not key

Comment: i dont know i dont have written the sql file, its from another developer.

Comment: As them where that came from then, and whether it runs at all

Comment: its a dump generated from a running db so i assume it works

Comment: What running db? What product? You can't just take a SQL script meant for one database and run it on another product, no matter what salesmen say to justify the lack of real backups in their products. There's a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint and a `UNIQUE` constraint, not `UNIQUE KEY`. Perhaps that script came from a product where `KEY` is allowed in `UNIQUE` but ignored

Comment: BTW using a `name` column instead of ID as a key is extremely unusual. Is this the *actual* query, or were parts of it removed? I'd expect `ID` to be the primary key and `name` to have a unique constraint

Comment: Yeah ID is in there to be the primary key. since the code is not from me i didnt blatenly post it here.

Comment: It also doesn't support named constraints. When in doubt, read the docs. https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html

Comment: OK if someone answers this ill accept this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As quoted here its not supported:
https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html